# Create Multiple records with fields_for - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models, `task` and `list_items`. a `task` has_many `list_items`. But I want to be able to be able to create `task` and many `list_items` if the user wants all in one form. Here is what it looks like currently:

#### FORM

```
<%= form_for @task, url: account_assignment_tasks_path(@assignment), method: :create do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :description, class: "form-input #{error_class}" %>

  <%= fields_for :list_items, @all_list_items do |list_item_form| %>
      <%= list_item_form.text_field :description, class: "form-input list-item", data: { list_item_field: "true" } %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### Task Controller

```
 def new
   @task = @assignment.tasks.new
   @list_item = @task.list_items.build
   @all_list_items = []
 end
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is create multiple list items and one task on create. But right now I'm getting this error if I submit the form

#### ERROR

```
undefined method `description' for []:Array
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong and how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> undefined method `description' for []:Array

To describe the reason for the error, `fields_for` accepts `record_object` as a second parameter which `fields_for` uses it to **construct** the fields. Here you are passing `@all_list_items` which is an array and that results in the error.

**Solution to the error:**

You should pass `@list_item` instead of `@all_list_items`

```
<%= fields_for :list_items, @list_item do |list_item_form| %>
```

**Solution to the actual problem:**

As you want to create multiple `list_items`, you should do

```
def new
  @task = @assignment.tasks.new
  x.times do
    @list_item = @task.list_items.build
  end
  @all_list_items = []
end
```

where `x` is how many `list_items` you want to create, for example if you want to create three `list_items`, then replace `x` with `3`.

**OR**

Use [*cocoon*](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem to dynamically create nested forms.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. However, I can't hardcode the x amount of records I want to create. It needs to be however many the user determines based on how many inputs they create. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Bitwise Yes, then I recommend to go with `cocoon`. Have a look at it :)

Comment: @Pavan thanks for the suggestion about `cocoon`.  I had my own [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65160367/rails-set-additional-attribute-on-has-many-through-record/65161683#65161683) and was able to do what I needed with `coccon`.