# Rails has_many form optionally create multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a `Profile` model and I'm trying to see if that profile has used any other names in the past. I came up with adding a `AdditionalName` model, and the association is `Profile has_many AdditionalName`. In the form, I would like for them to fill out up to 5 additional names. I saw from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533686/create-multiple-records-with-fields-for-rails) I can build it `x.times` and use `f.fields_for :additional_names` to show 5 additional names. Problem is, it will save all 5 when I submit the form, even if they don't fill anything. Is it possible that the `AdditionalName` records only save when they fill out something in the input field?

additional_name.rb

```
class AdditionalName < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :additional_names
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :additional_names
end
```

controller:

```
def new
existing_additional_names = @profile.additional_names.count
(5 - existing_additional_names).times do
  @current_object.additional_names.build
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_with model: @profile, url: wizard_path, method: :patch, local: true do |f| %>
  <div class="form-row">
    <%= f.fields_for :additional_names do |additional_names_form| %>
      <%= additional_names_form.hidden_field :id %>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <%= additional_names_form.label :name, "Full name" %>
          <%= additional_names_form.text_field :name, class: "form-control", id: "ignore-button-disable" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
      <%= f.submit 'Continue', class: 'btn btn-primary w-100' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a custom logic if you just want the nested records to be created only if a certain attribute is set. You can pass option [:reject_if](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) to `accepts_nested_attributes_for` call in the model with a lambda to handle it.

From the definition:

> Allows you to specify a Proc or a Symbol pointing to a method that checks whether a record should be built for a certain attribute hash.

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :additional_names,
                               reject_if: -> { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to overwrite `additional_names_attributes=` in the model:

```
def additional_names_attributes=(additional_name_attributes)
  additional_name_attributes.values.each do |additional_name_attribute|
    unless additional_name_attribute[:name].empty?
      additional_name = AdditionalName.find_or_create_by(additional_name_attribute)
      self.additional_names << additional_name
    end
  end
end
```