# Rails - Set additional attribute on has_many through record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using Rails 6.0.3.3 and ruby '2.6.0'.

I have these 3 models connected via a `has_many through` relation.

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :layers
  has_many :glazes, through: :layers
end

class Glaze < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :layers
  has_many :recipes, through: :layers
end

class Layer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :glaze
  # there is a column named "coat_type" here that I would like to set
end
```

Everything is working great for creating a new `Recipe` and it automagically creating its related `Layer` record.  But now I would like to also set a `coat_type` attribute on the `Layer` record when it's created, but I can't seem to figure out how I could do something like that.

The Form View Partial

```
= form_with model: recipe, local: true do |form|
  %p
    = form.label :name
    %br
    = form.text_field :name
  %p
    = form.label :description
    %br
    = form.text_area :description
  .recipe-glaze
    = form.collection_select(:glaze_id, Glaze.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Select Glaze" }, { name: 'recipe[glaze_ids][]' })  
  .recipe-glaze
    = form.collection_select(:glaze_id, Glaze.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Select Glaze" }, { name: 'recipe[glaze_ids][]' })  
  %p
    = form.submit
```

The Controller Create Action (and strong params acton)

```
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

  if @recipe.save
    redirect_to @recipe
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :description, glaze_ids: [])
end
```

Ideally, I would be able to add another select box in the form and the user would use that to set the `coat_type` of the `Layer` record that will be created.  But I can't figure out how I could pass that into the controller and have it know what to do with that value.

Is this something that is possible, or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

So I actually ended up stumbling upon the ["cocoon" gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45533847/3183532).  By following the setup instructions for "cocoon", I was able to tweak my code to do what I needed.

My `Recipe` model changed to this ::

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :layers, inverse_of: :recipe
  has_many :glazes, through: :layers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :layers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

My controller's strong params action changed to this ::

```
  private

  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :description, layers_attributes: [:id, :glaze_id, :coat_type, :_destroy])
  end
```

My form view partial changed to ::

```
  - if recipe.errors.any?
    = render partial: 'errors', locals: { recipe: recipe }
  %p
    = form.label :name
    %br
    = form.text_field :name
  %p
    = form.label :description
    %br
    = form.text_area :description
  %h3 Layers
  #layers
    = form.fields_for :layers do |layer|
      = render 'layer_fields', f: layer
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add layer', form, :layers
  %p
    = form.submit
```

and the "layer_fields" partial referenced in the form looks like this ::

```
.nested-fields
  .field
    = f.label :glaze_id
    %br
    = f.collection_select(:glaze_id, Glaze.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Select Glaze" } )
  .field
    = f.label :coat_type
    %br
    = f.text_field :coat_type
  = link_to_remove_association 'remove layer', f
```

Making those changes using the "Cocoon" gem, I was able to accomplish what I needed.  Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Glad you managed to fix it. Yet to me there is a problem with your relationship. Recipe has_many glazes, but also glaze has_many recipes. I think one should belong to the other and not every one of them own the other.

Comment: @Maxence Thx for the response.  I'm not sure if maybe this is the reason it works or not, but new `Glaze` records aren't created when a `Recipe` is created.  All `Glaze` records already exist in the DB and are more or less just static "options" that you can pick from.  When I run `recipe.glazes` I get all of the glazes for that particular recipe instance and when I run `glaze.recipes`, I get back every recipe that the glaze has been associated with.  So it may sound odd that both models have many of eachother, but it does function as I need it to.

Comment: Sure there are many different ways to do things and if it works I wouldn't really change it. Yet usually parent/child relationships are reciprocal (A has_many B, and B belongs_to A). With foreign key being on the child (B holds an a_id column). I recommend also in your case an has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. It involves the creation of "man in the middle" table and is slightly more complex to use. But it would suit well your case (if you end up changing the relationships at some point).